# Set the value of a Javascript input hidden field to that of a value entered in another input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, hidden

I have an input text field (`name: qtyText`) to which a user enters a value. I would like to set this value as the value for another hidden field (`name: qtyTextHidden`) using JavaScript. How can I go about it?

HTML

```
<input name = "qtyText" type = "textbox" size = "2" value = "" />
<input type="hidden"  value = "" name="qtyTextHidden"/>
```

My efforts to set the field value using JS work, but I am unable to send the value to the servlet. So I am attempting to directly set the value using a function and then try and send it to the servlet. I would like to have a `value = someJSFunction()` kind. The function needs to trigger upon "onChange" in the "qtyText" input field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:text[name="qtyText"]').keyup(function() {
        $('input:hidden[name="qtyTextHidden"]').val( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Using JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(document.readyState == 'complete') {
        document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onkeyup = function() {
            document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = this.value;
        };
    }
}:
```

Comment: Thanks all of you. The issue though seems to be slightly different. I am able to set the value of the hidden field. However, when I pass it on to a servlet, the value will be null on the servlet field. I checked with another dynamically generated value and its the same issue. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function updateHidden(valueFrom, valueTo) {
    valueTo.value = valueFrom.value;
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    textInputs = [],
    hiddenInputs = [],
    refersTo;

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    switch (inputs[i].type) {
        case 'hidden':
            hiddenInputs.push(inputs[i]);
            break;
        case 'text':
        default:
            textInputs.push(inputs[i]);
            break;
    }
}

for (var i = 0, len = textInputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    refersTo = document.getElementsByName(textInputs[i].name + 'Hidden')[0];
    if (refersTo !== null) {
        textInputs[i].onchange = function () {
            updateHidden(this, document.getElementsByName(this.name + 'Hidden')[0]);
        };
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YmCWb/1/).

Incidentally: there is ***no*** `type="textbox"`. At all. *Ever*. ***Anywhere*** in HTML, not even in HTML 5: it's `type="text"`. The only reason it *works* with `type="textbox"` is because browsers are ridiculously forgiving and, if the `type` isn't understood, it *defaults* to `type="text"`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I feel that I need to modify a bit to adopt this answer. Will try that and update my response.

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of the hidden field the easiest way is to use the javascript function that to pass three parameters `from`, `to`, and `form` names:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function someJSFunction(form, from, to){
      var el_from=form[from], el_to=form[to];
      el_to.value=el_from.value;
      return el_to.value;
    }
</script>
<form name="myform">
<input name = "qtyText" type = "textbox" size = "2" value = "" onchange="someJSFunction(myform, 'qtyText', 'qtyTextHidden')"/>
<input type="hidden"  value = "" name="qtyTextHidden"/>
```