# How to send JavaScript array to Servlet inside form tag?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I have made checkbox code and on checkbox click I am calling function which will add passed argument to JavaScript array.
I have taken form tag inside body and inside form tag there is only checkboxes and a button.
On button click servlet will called so I want some mechanism that will also send Java Script array data to servlet with checkbox value.

onClick of checkbox I am not passing checkbox value, I am passing other details so need other function to add data in array and pass it to servlet.

checkbox code :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="demo_box_2<%= aname %><%= aval %><%=k %>" class="css-checkbox" name="configcheckbox" value="<%= aval %>" onchange="addcategory('<%= acid %>')">
<label for="demo_box_2<%= aname %><%= aval %><%=k %>" name="demo_lbl_2<%=k %>" class="css-label">&nbsp;<%= aval %></label>
```

JavaScript function :

```
            var acdata = [];
            function addcategory(acid)
            {
                    acdata.push(acid);
                    //alert(acid);
            }
```

the code of checkbox is inside form tag, so I also want to send acdata[] array with checkbox value to servlet, so any help please ?

Comment: try sending `JSON.stringify(acdata)`, and then `JSON.parse` it later

Comment: where I ll have to parse in servlet ?

Comment: Umm, don't know much about servlets, but parse it wherever you want to access those array values. If it doesn't support `JSON.parse`(which is quite possible, for all I know) use string manipulations, treating the string inside the '[' and ']' as comma separated values

Comment: something like :`$.getJSON("addtocart?pid=" + pId`

Comment: Is that your servlet code? Try putting `acDataArray = JSON.parse(data.acdata)` in the `done` method(where data.acdata contains the stringified array string)

Comment: No it's javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code as Santosh explained,

In your script (**Edited**),

```
var acdata = [];
function addcategory(acid)
{
    acdata.push(acid);
    $("#hidden_array").val(acdata);
}
```

In your html,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="demo_box_2<%= aname %><%= aval %><%=k %>" 
class="css-checkbox" 
name="configcheckbox" value="<%= aval %>" onchange="addcategory('<%= acid %>')">
<label for="demo_box_2<%= aname %><%= aval %><%=k %>" name="demo_lbl_2<%=k %>" 
class="css-label">&nbsp;<%= aval %></label>
```

With this add one more hidden field inside your form like this,

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_array" name="hiddenArray" >
```

Hence you can get the array values in your jsp/servlet like this,

```
request.getParameterValues("hiddenArray");
```

PS: You can use **string array** `String[]` to process your data.

Comment: Shall I have to put `$("#hidden_array").val(acid);` code inside function or outside ? If I ll put it outside when it will be executed ?

Comment: and if I am going to use String [] then I ll have to use `request.getParameterValues("hiddenconfig");` because it ll accept array.

Comment: Yes, You need to use `$("#hidden_array").val(acid);` inside the function.

Comment: It add data when clicked on checkbox but also add data when loop executes. I have loop to dynamically fetch data in checkbox. It fill data with checkbox click value as well as other as blank, it fills blank data till loop iterates.

Comment: when I select checkbox and send request to servlet it pass array as `(2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)`.

Comment: Because you are passing only the checkbox selected value to the function. What is your actual need? If i understood you correctly, you need to add each selected checkbox value into that array? If so you need to set `$("#hidden_array").val(acdata);` outside of your function

Comment: If i put `$("#hidden_array").val(acid);` outside the loop it only send one value to servlet, all want to store all values that is array to hidded filed and then pass to servlet. In short all `acdata[]` value to servlet.

Comment: Instead trying send values everytime, check all checkboxes and use function finally to get all the selected values. Also i have noted that you are setting different id and different name to checkboxes. Use the same name for collect all selected checkbox value.

Comment: Yes Yes, `$("#hidden_array").val(acdata);` works awesome. I have used `acid` and when I used `acdata` array then it works sir, thank you sir ji.

Comment: You are welcome, Your upvote/ mark this as accepted answer will make this conversation more useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve this,

1. Create a hidden field inside the form,
2. Convert Javascript array to a comma/pipe separated string, (example [1](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12632), [2](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp))
3. Set the value of the hidden field to this string, (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312564/set-the-value-of-a-javascript-input-hidden-field-to-that-of-a-value-entered-in-a))
4. This way, when you submit the form, the hidden field data is also sent to server,
5. On the server side, split the string to get the data back as array of Java strings.

Comment: I am not understanding step 2 and 3 exactly, I have tried to pas using Hidden but I cant' pass data only of checked, it sends data of all if it is checked or not, so will you tell me how to add data in hidden field and pass it to servlet ?

Comment: I have added relevant example links.